# How to block all internet traffic on local linux machine expect one url

Tags: linux, iptables

I have my local(home) computer on Linux 16.04 system. How i can block all internet traffic except only one/few url's?

I'm trying to use `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s facebook.com -p tcp --sport www -j ACCEPT
```

But this implementatin doesn't work. Where do I have an error? Or maybe I need to use something else instead of `iptables`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to block all incomming traffic except an specific range, you should first change the default policy of the INPUT chain to DROP:

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
```

Then, you should give a netmask to `iptables` to allow many IP addresses altogether exceptionally. For example, if you need to only allow `74.231.64.1`, `74.231.64.2`, to `74.231.64.255`, you can use following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 74.231.64.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

`74.231.64.0/24` tells to iptables to apply the same role to all varying IPs between `74.231.64.1` to `74.231.64.255`. Similarly, you can widen this range by passing `74.231.0.0/16` or `74.0.0.0/8` instead.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Before applying this change, you better have a direct access to the system, not an over-network access. This is because a miss type may block you from the server.